# Accessing a variable in a function other than return value

Tags: php, function, variables

I need an help to understand this problem I am facing...and apologies if it seems silly.

I wrote a function that makes some calculations according to two differents dates (arrival and departure). It all works fine, the returned values is given and it is correct.

Nevertheless while this calculation is made there is variable created ($days) which I would like to use (echo) outside the function. I have tried to make it global but I get an error...guessing that I am on the wrong path!

So my question is how do you get a value inside a function other than the returned value? if it is at all possible of course.

code below:

```
function costs($date1, $date2, $price) {

$arr= explode("/", $date1);
$timestamp1 = mktime(0,0,0,$arr[1],$arr[0],$arr[2]);

$arr2= explode("/", $date2);
$timestamp2 = mktime(0,0,0,$arr2[1],$arr2[0],$arr2[2]);

$timestamp = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1;
$days = $timestamp/86400;

$cost = $days * $price;

return $cost;

}
```

Appreciated any little help to understand this.
Francesco

Comment: You need to post your code, and be more specific about what "I get an error" means. As it is, this isn't really a question.

Comment: I find it odd how no one recommended references. If you want a function to be able to change more than variable, then you pass one or more variables by reference. They will be modified and available outside of the function scope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These should really be two separate functions, with the one using the other.

```
function costs($date1, $date2, $price) {
    $cost = days($date1, $date2) * $price;
    return $cost; 
}

function days($date1, $date2) {
    $arr= explode("/", $date1); 
    $timestamp1 = mktime(0,0,0,$arr[1],$arr[0],$arr[2]); 

    $arr2= explode("/", $date2); 
    $timestamp2 = mktime(0,0,0,$arr2[1],$arr2[0],$arr2[2]); 

    $timestamp = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1; 

    return $timestamp/86400;
}
```

EDIT: Then you can call either function depending on what you want without duplicating code.

It doesn't look like you're using objects, so I won't give you the OO spiel, but you can definitely split these up into separate functions so you're not doing wierd stuff with globals and muddying up your namespaces.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. I tried your solution and work perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes it works - but it's an appalling bad solution - it's inefficient - it displaces related concerns and its entirely unnecessary.

Comment: What do you propose syncbean?

Comment: I would say that calculating a cost and calculating the difference between two date are unrelated concerns and shouldn't be lumped into the same function. Worrying about inefficiency at this stage sounds like a problem of premature optimization. You could also rewrite the cost calculator to take the $days variable if you find yourself doing the calculations together most of the time.

Comment: Keeping the two calculations separated might turn out to be a good thing in the future. I might need just one of them a time. I am still developing the all thing. Will see. Thank you to all fo you.

Answer (score 0):

For specific to ur code...try this

```
function costs($date1, $date2, $price) {

$arr= explode("/", $date1);
$timestamp1 = mktime(0,0,0,$arr[1],$arr[0],$arr[2]);

$arr2= explode("/", $date2);
$timestamp2 = mktime(0,0,0,$arr2[1],$arr2[0],$arr2[2]);

$timestamp = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1;
$days = $timestamp/86400;

$cost = $days * $price;

$arr = array();
$arr['cost'] = $cost;
$arr['days'] = $days;
return $arr;

}
```

Comment: Hi Poonam, I have tried the 3rd method but  i got an error: Notice: Undefined variable: days.

Comment: the $days varialbe is created inside the function.

Comment: I have updated my post...I have added specific to ur code...check this

Comment: **$arr = array();$arr['cost'] = $cost;
$arr['days'] = $days;
return $arr;**
added to ur fuction...so outside of function u will get both values in array

Comment: Hi Poonam. I like your solution with array but I will go with the two function proposed by Joseph Erickson. Thank you really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it up in a class, so you can access the $days..

`

```
class Something {
  public $days;

  public function calc($arrival, $departure)
  {
    // Do your thing
    $this -> days = $days;
    return $something;
  }

  public function getDays()
  {
    return $this -> days;
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In your function, include an optional parameter. If this is set, then return the date /instead/ of the difference.

```
<?php
function fn($arrival, $departure, $getDate = FALSE)
{
  //your function stuff
  ...

  //if optional flag is set, then return number of days.
  if($getDate)
  {
    return $days;
  }

  //if flag not set, then return original value.
  return $values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the $cost value returned by the function, and you know the $price value that you're passing into the function when you call it; then

```
$days = $cost / $price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either return an array from your function, or send a reference to the destination into the function by way of a parameter.

```
list ($cost, $return_days)=costs("01/03/2011", "17/03/2011", 100, $ref_days);
// $ref_days and $return_days now hold the same value

function costs($date1, $date2, $price, &$days) {
  ...
  $days = $timestamp/86400;
  $cost = $days * $price;
  return array($cost,$days);
}
```

Comment: I am looking into your code symcbean, although there os no $days outside the function to reference to. Unless I am misunderstang your code.

Comment: I understood and made your code work for me Sy. Yes I think is a good solution.